How to disallow specific fragment URLs using robots.txt?
How do you disallow dynamic URLs that have the following path in the robots.txt file.
https://example.com/blogs/news/nameofthepost#How-Much-do-they-cost
The posts do have canonical set but that didn't matter and the dynamic URLs were all indexed.
I tested using:
Disallow: /*#

But that didn't work for the direct path I am trying to disallow.

There is no way to use robots.txt to disallow crawling of URL fragments (with a hash symbol #) in the URL.  That is because hash URLs are never fetched from the server and can't be "crawled" to begin with.
When a browser wants to display https://example.com/blogs/news/nameofthepost#How-Much-do-they-cost it fetches the URL without the fragment from the server:  https://example.com/blogs/news/nameofthepost and then runs the JavaScript in the page that may pay attention to the fragment identifier and change the content accordingly.
robots.txt is only meant to limit which URLs are fetched from the server.  Since the fragment identifier is never fetched from the server, trying to disallow it in robots.txt is meaningless.
If your goal is to prevent a page from getting indexed by search engines, you should instead disallow a JavaScript file that processes that URL fragment, or use meta noindex tags.
